# Split the end of a string in C++ using string delimiter (,)

Tags: c++, string, split

I have the below format of a string:

```cpp
str1 = "a, b, c, d, e";
str2 = "aa, ba, ca, da, essd";
str2 = "aass, bsda, cads, dsda, esssdsd";
```

I want to extract the end of the string after splitting --> `e`, `essd`, `esssdsd`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming these are `std::string`s, I'd use `rfind` to find the last occurrence of the delimiter, and then take a substring from there. E.g.:

```
size_t index = str.rfind(", ");
string last_element = str.substr(index + 2); // 2 is the size of the delimiter
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked.